# Create random time stamp list in python

Tags: python, random, timestamp

Is there a way to create a list of random irregular time stamps in strictly increasing format in Python? For example:

```
20/09/2013 13:00        
20/09/2013 13:01        
20/09/2013 13:05        
20/09/2013 13:09        
20/09/2013 13:16        
20/09/2013 13:26
```

Comment: does `irregular` mean `unique`? what are yo using the timestamps for?

Comment: Irregular as in time gap between two successive time stamps should be uneven. And should also being unique. Im trying to generate a random irregularly sampled time series.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can build a random generator.

- You can generate `randrange(60)` radom number between 0-60 (minutes)
- use `timedelta` to add time to the actual date, in your case, it's `20/09/2013 13:..`
- build a generator `random_date`, with a starting date, and number of dates that you wanna generate.

> ```
> from random import randrange
> import datetime 
>
>
> def random_date(start,l):
>    current = start
>    while l >= 0:
>       curr = current + datetime.timedelta(minutes=randrange(60))
>       yield curr
>       l-=1
>
>
>
> startDate = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20,13,00)
>
> for x in random_date(startDate,10):
>   print x.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
> ```

Output:

```
20/09/13 13:12
20/09/13 13:02
20/09/13 13:50
20/09/13 13:13
20/09/13 13:56
20/09/13 13:40
20/09/13 13:10
20/09/13 13:35
20/09/13 13:37
20/09/13 13:45
20/09/13 13:27
```

**UPDATE**

You can trick that by adding the difference number to the last date that you have generated, then reverse the over-all list. 
You can also change the random number that you add everytime, to get the results that you want.

Your code would look like.

```
from random import randrange
import datetime 


def random_date(start,l):
   current = start
   while l >= 0:
    current = current + datetime.timedelta(minutes=randrange(10))
    yield current
    l-=1



startDate = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20,13,00)


for x in reversed(list(random_date(startDate,10))):
    print x.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

Output:

```
20/09/13 13:45
20/09/13 13:36
20/09/13 13:29
20/09/13 13:25
20/09/13 13:20
20/09/13 13:19
20/09/13 13:16
20/09/13 13:16
20/09/13 13:07
20/09/13 13:03
20/09/13 13:01
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i require the time stamps to be in increasing order. Is there a way to modify the above code?

Comment: Welcome! you can reverse the generated list, check the UPDATE where I added more details.

Comment: Yes thats what i had tried. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: any way to get timestamps in increasing order based on this?