# Create random minutes date between given hours

Tags: datetime, random, anaconda

Desired output:
Time gap in given range of time, namely from 5:30 to 8:15
Something like:

```
05:17   
07:01        
06:05        
06:09        
05:16        
07:26
```

Tried this one:
[Create random time stamp list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740227/create-random-time-stamp-list-in-python)
but getting an error in:

```
for x in random_date(startDate,10):
  print x.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: print x.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, do the following:

1. Convert the start time (hours and minutes) to a number of minutes; for example, 
   `startTime = startHours * 60 + startMinutes`.
2. Convert the end time (hours and minutes) to a number of minutes; for example, 
   `endTime = endHours * 60 + endMinutes`.
3. Generate a random integer between the start time and the end time; for example,
   `random.randint(startTime + 1, endTime - 1)`.
4. Convert the random integer to hours and minutes.